# Making a Transparent image button with bgcolor

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uibutton, transparency, background-color

I have a transparent image which ("hold_empty.png", below) which I want to turn into a button. Inside the button there will be a view with a colored background which is slightly smaller size than the actual image to hold the background color.

The reason for this is because the image has rounded corners and so I cannot simply put a background color on the image as it will appear to be bigger than the image.

[image]

The image is a transparent square with "rounded corners". The effect I am trying to create should be like layers.

1. Background color layer (red, green, etc)
2. The "hold_empty.png" picture (above)
3. The whole object (including bg color layer) should be clickable.

The problem I am experiencing is that only the image (and its borders) appears to be clickable, and not the whole object.

The code follows below.

```
// x,y,w,h
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 72, 72);
CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(5, 5, 60, 60); // I know this is not filling the image, its just a test

UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame2];
[bgColorView setFrame:frame2];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hold_empty" ofType:@"png"]];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn addSubview:bgColorView];
[btn setImage:image  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.frame = frame;
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelectColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[self.view addSubview:btn];
[bgColorView release];
```

So, to summarize: How do I make a transparent image button with a background color clickable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cracked it now. One of the problems I was having was that it was not working with avatars (sometimes it would appear behind the layer, othertimes it would not show at all).

This is my solution.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"some_avatar" ofType:@"png"]];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    CGRect fullFrame = CGRectMake(25, 10, 70,72);   
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(28, 13, 63,65);

    UIButton *h=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [h setFrame:fullFrame];
    [[h layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
    //[h setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[h setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [h setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [h setClipsToBounds:YES];
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    [gradientLayer setBounds:frame];
    [gradientLayer setPosition:CGPointMake([h bounds].size.width/2, [h bounds].size.height/2)];
    [gradientLayer setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor]CGColor],(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil]];
    [[h layer] insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
    [h insertSubview:imgView atIndex:1];
    [h addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelectColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:h];
    [imgView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

The clickable area is generally the `frame` of the button which would not be clipped by its super-views, if you would let them clip contents.

The fact that you *see* something on screen doesn't mean it's "visible" in the sense that you can touch it. If you let every view clip its subviews (through IB, or by setting `view.clipsToBounds = YES;`) then any problems in that respect will show up clearly.

(Note that any `UIButton`, `UIImageView`, etc is a `view` and can be set to clip its contents)

Comment: I tried putting clipToBounds first on UIView *bgColorView, then the *btn, then both; regardless of where I forced the clipToBounds to be true, it would simply give me the same result -- the image itself is clickable, but not the colored background part.  I tried removing the bgColor layer and simply putting in a background color to the btn with clipToBounds = YES, but it still overlaps the image.  I might have missed something with your explanation though.

Comment: Odd. The (background) area you're talking about is only 5px wide on top and left, and 17px on right and bottom, right?

Comment: The background area is the dimensions you specify because I am only testing to see whether it is clickable regardless of its size.  It will be the same size as the image (minus a few pixels) in the final version.

Comment: CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(5, 5, 60, 60);  Its not 5px wide top/left, thats the x and y if I am not mistaken.  The last two parameters are the width and height.

Comment: Exactly, but if your container (background) is 72*72, and you put in something at 5,5, sized 50*50, then you have an unequal border of 5px left/top and 72-50-5=17px bottom/right. Which sounds rather unusual. (I see you changed the numbers in your question)

Comment: I changed the numbers because its not meant to start at 0,0. Also, its a test to see if the whole button object would be clickable.  I'll be changing the size again to fit the entire 72*72 region.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to maybe enable user interaction on the subview?

```
bgColorView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: I tried adding userInteractionEnabled to the bgColorView first and then to the btn (although it is not necessary to do this), but this didn't make the background color view clickable.  Upon reading about userInteractionEnabled, it says you can use it like an IBAction so I might be able to fake a btn click with just the bgColorView layer, but the problem is that in the future I might want to put another transparent layer ontop of the bgColorView.  I'll try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have an answer that is working, but would like your comments/suggestions.

I created an UIImageView and put my background color layer and image layer inside that and then put the UIImageView inside the btn.

The only problem is now the button does not look like it is being pressed.

When I add the "setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted" option it has what looks like a big white star in the middle of the button when the user clicks ont he button.

[image]

```
// x,y,w,h
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 72, 72);
CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(5, 5, 62, 62); // This fits, but may not be 100% accurate

// View
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame2];
[bgColorView setFrame:frame2];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
bgColorView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[bgColorView setNeedsDisplayInRect:frame2];

// Image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hold_empty2" ofType:@"png"]];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imgView insertSubview:bgColorView atIndex:0];

// Btn
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setFrame:frame];
[btn addSubview:imgView];
[btn setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
[btn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelectColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:btn];

[imgView release];
[bgColorView release];
```